# Blazor: How do I check whether field is valid in OnFieldChanged

Tags: c#, validation, blazor

I want to call a method when user changes a specific field AND the field value is valid.

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext">
   <DataAnnotationValidator /> //could be FluentValidator or anything else
   <InputText @bind="Model.Username" />
</EditForm>
```

```
_editContext = new EditContext(Model);
_editContext.FieldChanged(o, e) => {
   if (e.FieldIdentifier.Name == "Username") {
       //how to check if field is valid
       //folowing does not work, because field has not been validated yet
       var hasSrrors = e.EditContext.GetValidationMessages(e.FieldIdentifier).Any();
   }
};
```

**How do I check whether the field is valid after it has changed?**

I've come with RX solution, but it is not perfect:

```cs
Model.EditContext.FieldChangedObservable()
    .Where(fieldIdenitfier => fieldIdenitfier.Name == "Username")
    //wait until validation
    .Select(_ => Model.EditContext.ValidationStateChangedObservable().FirstAsync())
    .Switch()
    //check barcode validation
    .Where(b => !Model!.EditContext.GetValidationMessages(FieldIdentifier.Create(() => Model.Entity.Barcode)).Any())
    .Subscribe(_ => MyFieldChanged());
```

Comment: EditContext has a method "Validate()", with which you can manually trigger validation.

Comment: The problem is, that it will validate the entire form and show errors everywhere. This is not something you want to do when single field changes. For example, in sign-up form, you don't want to show "password is required", when a user types something into Username field